# Why is my angular directive causing incomplete values to be deleted upon tabbing to another field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On a project I'm working on, I have a U.S. phone directive that is giving me some trouble.  The short of it is, if you enter an incomplete value and tab to another field, the value is lost.

I've created [a plunker of the problem in motion](http://plnkr.co/edit/yOExBihqrV4JUWRc5Jvp), and the offending directive is below:

```
angular.module('app').directive('someInput', [
  '$filter', someInputDir
]);

function someInputDir($filter) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      // Build mask.
      var mask = '(999) 999-9999';
      if (attrs.useExtension)
        mask += attrs.useExtension.toLowerCase() === 'true' ? '? x99999' : '';

      $(element).mask(mask);

      var nonDigitCharacters = /[^0-9]/g;

      // HACK: It turns out that angular and the jQuery Masked Input plugin
      // don't play nicely together.  In order for the masked input to work properly,
      // we have to bind an event handler for key down events (since Masked Input
      // blocks key down events) and force a change event to get the parsers to work
      // properly.
      element.on('keydown', function (evt) {
        scope.$evalAsync(element.triggerHandler.bind(element, 'change', evt));
      });

      ctrl.$validators.minLength = function (modelValue) {
        var minLength = 0;
        if (attrs.minlength)
          minLength = parseInt(attrs.minlength);

        var stringValue = $filter('tel')(modelValue, false),
            longEnough = stringValue.length >= minLength;

        // If value not required, and nothing is entered, the value is valid.
        if (!attrs.required && stringValue.length === 0)
          return true;

        // If value is required, and nothing is entered, this value is 'valid'.
        // The point of this code is to not interfere with a required attribute!
        if (attrs.required && stringValue.length === 0)
          return true;

        return longEnough;
      };

      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        var digitsOnly = viewValue.replace(nonDigitCharacters, '');                  
        return digitsOnly;
      });

      ctrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
        return $filter('tel')(value, false);
      });
    }
  };
}
```

At first, I thought it was the custom `$validator` that I created to simulate a minlength validation (this implementation causes a regular minlength to not work properly due to the mask.)  However, in my plunker, you will see that I made a version without the `$validator` that has the exact same problem.

**Question:** I don't understand what about this directive is causing an incomplete value to be deleted on blur.  Also, in what way can I prevent the invalid value from being deleted, but allowing the field to still be tagged as invalid?

Comment: Your problem in `scope.$evalAsync(element.triggerHandler.bind(element, 'change', evt));`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko That's very good to know.  What about it is causing this issue, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an issue with JQuery maskedinput plugin.
Try change `$(element).mask(mask);` to  `$(element).mask(mask, {autoclear:false});`

Here is plunker with changes http://plnkr.co/edit/b1knRUgREox2Su8xdVIN

Comment: I can't believe I didn't consider that.  I really need to spend more time reading documentation on APIs I use...